# Firefox HTTP connections spend a lot of time on blocking phase

Tags: ajax, http, firefox, panel, blocking

My application is performing a lot of consecutive XHR calls. This means establishing a lot of HTTP connections.

I'm trying to analyze the performance of all these connections. I found out that the first HTTP connection made spends about 10% of its duration on *Blocking* (following definition quoted from [Firebug Wiki](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel#Request_Timeline)):

> **Blocking** - *Time spent in a browser queue waiting for a network connection (formerly called Queueing). For SSL connections this includes the SSL Handshake and the OCSP validation step.*

In consecutive calls, the time spent on blocking increases, and after about 10 calls, the blocking holds steady at an average of ~120MS (!!!).

I've tried to measure the HTTP connections similarly in Chrome with the DevTools and in IE with Fiddler, and though they don't use the exact same stages/names for the different stages on an HTTP connection, neither shows signs of the inordinate amount of time spent on blocking that Firefox does.

I can exclude that it's a lack of available (persistent) HTTP connections. Since the XHR calls are done synchronously.

Anyone familiar with this Firefox behaviour? If necessary, I can show the Firebug Net Panel output.

Comment: Do you mean that the XHR calls are behing done asynchronously?  If they are synchronous, blocking would be the expected behavior.

Comment: No, they are explicitly synchronous. One after another, never more than 1 at a time.

Answer (score 5):

Firefox only has a limit to the number of active HTTP(S) connections at any given time.  This is controlled by the preference `network.http.max-connections-per-server` (restart required after a change).  I strongly suspect you are hitting this limit.

Comment: Here's a more up-to-date (as of August 2019) documentation on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/request_details#Timings http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server